# How to identify if a web-service provider supports Asynchronous invocation of WS, by looking at WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous

I am in a situation where we are consuming a lot of web services. Currently it is in sequential fashion.
We're brainstorming multiple options on how to improve performance and one of the option is to invoke WS  in parallel. I think asynchronous WS invocation can work best.

The question is: 
1) If Asynch WS invocation can be transparent to WS provider?(meaning no additional changes needed to support this )

2) If it is not transparent, then by investigating the WSDL, can we figure out if WS provider supports such type of invocation?

Answer (score 0):

I presume that these services are external, or not under your control. I would expect that the service will act the same in the future as they do today. Your issue, if I have understood you correctly, is that you now plan to call many services concurrently. This has less to do with the services themselves, rather than how you co-ordniate the many different responses arriving at different times and order.